# Random opening tabs/pills - bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to open on every new site load another random tab with content.
i think i have to do it with some java script but it don´t work.

You can look at the page here: [LINK](https://amphire.de/dev/team/)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use this code :

var items = $('[data-toggle=pill]');
var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length));
$('#tabs a:eq(' + i + ') ').tab('show');
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked perfect! You saved my day and get some karma from germany :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select **all available tabs** (the code below uses jQuery which is available on your page)
2. Draw a **random item**
3. "Simulate" a **click event**

You can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    var items = $('[data-toggle=pill]');
    var randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

    randomItem.trigger('click');
});
```